# Django abstract model override method for limit_choices_to

Tags: django, inheritance, model, abstract-class

Here are my models:

```
class BudgetName(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    type = models.IntegerField(default=0,choices=((0,'incomes'),(1,'outcomes')))

class FinancialModel(models.Models):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def my_limit_choices():
        return None

    """ Here goes some price fields, not important here """
    budgetname = models.ForeignKey(BudgetName, limit_choices_to= my_limit_choices)

class Incomes(FinancialModel):
    def my_limit_choices():
        return {'type':0}

class Outcomes(FinancialModel):
    def my_limit_choices():
        return {'type':1}
```

It works fine in abstract class - when I try to filter something in my_limit_choices method. However, it seems that they are not overriden in child classes. Why and how to solve that?

Comment: Nope, that's ok. Otherwise it throws: `my_limit_choices() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to make `limit_choices_to` call the instance method `my_limit_choices`.

Another approach is to define a custom model form, and set the queryset in the `__init__` method.

```
class FinancialModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyOrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['budgetname'].queryset = BudgetName.objects.filter(**self.instance.my_limit_choices())
```

Then use this form in your model admins:

```
class IncomesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = FinancialModelForm

class OutcomesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = FinancialModelForm

admin.site.register(Incomes, IncomesAdmin)
admin.site.register(Outcomes, OutcomesAdmin)
```